# Filtering an arraylist using a method

Tags: java, list, search, methods, filter

I am trying to return a list of doctors who have a patient based on a date given by the user. But each time I run the method, it returns the list of all doctors instead of being filtered.

Code on Main

```
public void printDoctorsWithPatientsOnDate() throws ParseException
{
    ArrayList<String> docs = new ArrayList();
    System.out.print("Enter the date(mm-dd-yyyy): ");
    Date dt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").parse(sc.nextLine());
    docs = app.getDoctorsWithPatientsOnDate(dt);
    for(String i : docs)
    {
    System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Method for filtering

```
public ArrayList<String> getDoctorsWithPatientsOnDate(Date date)
{
    ArrayList<String> doctors = new ArrayList();
    for(Patient i : patientList)
    {
        if(i.searchDatesForDoc(date) == true);
        {
            doctors.add(i.getDoctorName());
        }
    }
    return doctors;
}
```

Method for searching the dates of a patient

```
public boolean searchDatesForDoc(Date date){
    for(Date i : datesOfVisit)
    {
        if(i.equals(date))
        {
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have initialized 2 patients namely patient1 and patient 2. patient1's doctor is named dr.lee and patient 2's doctor is named dr.james. first, i enter the following information for patient1 and i left patient2 with nothing(for now).

```
Enter the Patient's name: patient1
Enter the assessment: alz
Enter the date of Visit(mm-dd-yyyy): 10-02-2010
```

and the problem comes when I get the list of doctors. Even though the date is wrong, it keeps on printing the every doctor on the list.

```
Enter the date(mm-dd-yyyy): 11-20-2012
dr.lim
dr.james
```

Comment: `if (i.serachDatesForDoc(date)==true)` - you don't need the `==true` there. As `searchDatesForDoc` returns a Boolean you can just use that as the condition.  I doubt this is your problem - I can't see why it would be - but it may help.

Comment: @MrB I tried what you said but nothing happened. I still have the same problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason (to me anyway), the accepted answer that I gave was deleted by a moderator.
The problem has been resolved. The problem was that he had an extra semicolon after the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the code to reproduce, but I would focus on the searchDatesForDoc method first.  Try this:

```
public ArrayList<String> getDoctorsWithPatientsOnDate(Date date)
{
    ArrayList<String> doctors = new ArrayList();
    for(Patient i : patientList)
    {
        System.out.println("Current patient is: " + i.getPatientName());
        if(i.searchDatesForDoc(date) == true);
        {
            doctors.add(i.getDoctorName());
        }
    }
    return doctors;
}

public boolean searchDatesForDoc(Date date){
    for(Date i : datesOfVisit)
    {
        if(i.equals(date))
        {
            System.out.println("\tVisited on day: " + i);
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When you run with those two lines added, it will print the patient name followed with the days that the patient visited.  First thing to check is whether or not the patient actually did visit on those dates listed.  If not, then your problem is there.  This would be a lot easier to debug with a debugger to trace through each step of your code.

Comment: tried what you said and here's the output. I entered the wrong date and it still printed the doctors lol
    Enter the date(mm-dd-yyyy): 10-02-2010
    Current patient is: patient1
    Current patient is: patient2
    dr.lim
    dr.james

Comment: Now try moving the `System.out.println("Current...` command to within the `if` statement (so moving it two lines down).  Let us know what that does.